VS Code x VPS - executing remote code in interactive session
I'm trying to test code and the easiest way would be interactive session which is great feature when working with data.
I'm connecting to VPS via SSH FFS extension, activated venv, installed ipykernel, and added venv to the kernel list via following command (this approach works in local environment)
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=.env --display-name "Python (myenv)"
I tried to copy kernel to local jupyter kernels folder /Users/john/Library/Jupyter/kernels/ but it doesn't work either
{
    "argv": [
     "/home/vps/test/.env/bin/python",
     "-m",
     "ipykernel_launcher",
     "-f",
     "{connection_file}"
    ],
    "display_name": "VPS test",
    "language": "python",
    "metadata": {
     "debugger": true
    }
}

All extensions are installed, restarting vs code etc. doesn't help.
Any idea why I can't see remote venv in kernel list? It seems interactive session is reading only venv added locally via ipykernel command. Not sure if it's possible but maybe adding remote kernels directory (the VPS one) to the dir list that interactive session checks upon would solve the problem?
